# Как сохранить pdf по выбранному url и отдельных элементов div на сервер?

Tags: pdf, php

Добрый день.

Нужно создать pdf из элементов HTML страницы средствами php.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, на чём это реализовать?
Спасибо.